# How to fix bit length when doing bitshift right?

Tags: python, syntax, operator-keyword, bit-shift

I have generated x = 0 - 2047 in hexadecimal (0 - 7ff).
Then, I tried to shift one bit to right, but I want to keep all the value.

for example, for x = 2047 = h7ff.
I want to shift this value to right. can I set fixed bit length, so that even if I shift, it will not cut the 8?

tried:

```
x = 2047

hex(x)='0x7ff'

hex(x >> 1)='0x3ff'
```

expecting:

```
0x3ff8
```

Comment: `hex((0x7ff * 0x10) >> 1)` ?

Comment: What's the rule on adding a new hex digit to the front? Do you only want to do this if there will be an underflow?

Comment: yes. because I will combine this result in front of trailing zeros in hexa format.

Comment: `0x3ff8` is the result when you do `0x7ff << 3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra digit only if a bit in the result will be chopped off, you can use a simple modulo. Check if the last bit in the value is a `1`, and if it is, multiply the number by `0x10` or decimal `16` to add the extra padding. Then bit shift as normal.

```
hex((x * 0x10 if x % 2 == 1 else x) >> 1)
```

adding this to a method for reuse:

```
def rotate(x):
    return (x * 0x10 if x % 2 == 1 else x) >> 1


print(hex(x := 0x7ff))
print(hex(x := rotate(x)))
print(hex(x := rotate(x)))
print(hex(x := rotate(x)))
print(hex(x := rotate(x)))
```

```
0x7ff
0x3ff8
0x1ffc
0xffe
0x7ff
```